# Turn off access to pages that are not as links rewrite in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I write htaccess code that make my url seo friendly

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ page.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA]
```

the real page access format is `page.php?id={id}&title={title}`.

And with htaccess `p/{id}/{title}`

So want I want to stop access `page.php` with real format. is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You actually cannot prevent `page.php` from accessing it in real format. The code in your `.htaccess` file only rewrites the URL to be SEO friendly and it does not redirects or prevents it from accessing in real format.
For example these two links will both work without any error on your server:

```
<a href="page.php?id=1&title=asd">link1</a> // will redirect you to the original format
<a href="/page/1/asd/">link2</a> // will redirect you to the SEO friendly format
```

The only way to "prevent" accessing it from other users in real format is to change every link into SEO friendly (see `link2`) and belive in that the user does not know the original format!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule below your current rewrite rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^page.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```